# Prove by definition that $H_a$ is a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've got this question about groups, I know all definitions of a group that it has to be (Closure, Associativity,   Identity and Inverse), but I have no clue how to start this question. I'll be happy if someone could help.

Let $〈G,*〉$ be a group and $a\in G$, let $H_a=\{a*g*a^{-1} \mid g\in G\}$.
Prove by definition that $H_a$ is a group.

Comment: The elements of $Ha$ are the elements of $G$ [conjugated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) by $a$

Comment: Since $H_a = G$, the proofs in the answers are longer than necessary!

Comment: When you delete a downvoted post, like you did a few minutes ago, it counts against you when you've asked only zero score questions or downvoted posts prevail.  Deleting that downvoted post doesn't erase the damage done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a\in G$.

Observe that associativity in $H_a$ is inherited from $G$.

Since $e\in G$, we have $a\ast e\ast a^{-1}=a\ast a^{-1}=e\in H_a$.

Let $x=a\ast g\ast a^{-1}, y=a\ast h\ast a^{-1}\in H_a$. Then

$$\begin{align}
x\ast y&=(a\ast g\ast a^{-1})\ast (a\ast h\ast a^{-1})\\
&=a\ast g\ast (a^{-1}\ast a)\ast h\ast a^{-1}\\
&=a\ast g\ast e\ast h\ast a^{-1}\\
&=a\ast (g\ast h)\ast a^{-1}.
\end{align} $$

But $g\ast h\in G$ since $G$ is closed. Hence $x\ast y\in H_a$. Hence $H_a$ is closed.

Consider $x$ as an element of $G$. We have, by the [inverse of a product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Group_Product), that

$$\begin{align}
x^{-1}&=(a\ast g\ast a^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(a^{-1})^{-1}\ast g^{-1}\ast a^{-1}\\
&=a\ast g^{-1}\ast a^{-1},
\end{align}$$

because [the inverse of an inverse is the original element](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Group_Inverse). But $g^{-1}\in G$ as $G$ is a group. Hence $x^{-1}\in H_a$. Hence $H_a$ has inverses, which are simply the inverses of each element when considered as an element of $G$.

Hence $H_a$ is a group by definition.

Comment: Thanks that helped alot. Also last small question:
Can you tell me the proof of ** If G is Abelian then Ha=G** I'll be glad :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Haytham. As for your follow-up question, note that $$\begin{align} H_a&=\{a\ast g\ast a^{-1}\mid g\in G\} \\ &=\{ (a\ast g)\ast a^{-1}\mid g\in G\} \\ &=\{ (g\ast a)\ast a^{-1}\mid g\in G\} \text{ (since }G\text{ is abelian)}\\ &=\{ g\ast (a\ast a^{-1})\mid g\in G\} \\ &=\{ g\ast e\mid g\in G\}\\ &=\{ g\mid g\in G\}\\ &=G.\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry: @Haytham95.

Comment: But $H_a = G$ anyway, whether or not $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Indeed, but the exercise is to show that $H_a$ is a group *by definition*, @DerekHolt. It's like evaluating limits without l'Hôpital.

Comment: Yes, I expect you are right. I wasn't really sure what "Prove by definition" meant. But the proof that $H_a = G$ using only the definition of a group is still very short.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $H_a\subset G$. The question is whether it is a *subgroup*: does it contain the identity element $e$ of $G$, and is it closed under $*$ and under inverses? (You get associativity for free, since you're using the same operation $*$ as in $G$.)

So you want to show that:

1. $e$ is in $H_a$.
2. If $h_0$ and $h_1$ are in $H_a$, then $h_0 * h_1$ is also in $H_a$.
3. If $h$ is in $H_a$, then $h^{-1}$ is also in $H_a$.

For example, for 3: if $h \in H_a$, that means there's a $g \in G$ such that $h = a g a^{-1}$. Can you use this $g$ to show that $h^{-1}$ is in $H_a$?